# Metadata Item bug

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm creating a mod for minecraft and created a metadata item, it has three variants (default, 1 and 2).

when im trying to give it to my player with item:0 or nothing i get this item, and its id is just item without :number, but when i give item:1, the given item adds to stack to item:0. When i throw item:0 from inventory, item:1 successfully gives with it custom texture, but its id is item, not item:1

Here's my item with variants code:

```
    public Trowel(String name, CreativeTabs tab) {
        super(name, tab);
        this.tab = tab;
    }

    public void getSubItems(Item item, CreativeTabs tabs, List<ItemStack> list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < EnumTrowel.count(); i++) {
            list.add(new ItemStack(item, 1, i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack stack) {
        for(int i = 0; i < EnumTrowel.count(); i++) {
            if(stack.getItemDamage() == i) {
                return this.getUnlocalizedName() + "_" + EnumTrowel.values()[i].getName();
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return this.getUnlocalizedName() + "_" + EnumTrowel.CLEAR.getName();
    }
```

This is my Main class preInit()

```
    public static void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        proxy.registerModelBakeryStuff();
        RegistryHandler.registerCustomMeshesAndStates();
        RegistryHandler.registerFluid(concrete);
        for(int i = 0; i < EnumTrowel.count(); i++) {
            ModItems.registerRender(ModItems.TROWEL, i, "trowel_" + EnumTrowel.values()[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

And here's my ClientProxy register method

```
    @Override
    public void registerModelBakeryStuff() {
        ModelBakery.registerItemVariants(ModItems.TROWEL, new ResourceLocation(Reference.MOD_ID, "trowel_clear"), new ResourceLocation(Reference.MOD_ID, "trowel_plaster"), new ResourceLocation(Reference.MOD_ID, "trowel_gypsum"));
    }
```

item:0 = trowel_clear (default variant)

item:1 = trowel_plaster (1 variant)

item:2 = trowel_gypsum (2 variant)

There's no any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure what's going wrong, as you've hidden a few things behind other mehods that aren't really in places where they should be (why does `ModItems` have a `registerRender` method?)

Anyway, if I dissect [my own code](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1.12.1/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/client/ClientEasyRegistry.java#L140-L149)<sup>1</sup> regarding items with variants I notice two things:

1. I don't see anything equivalent to `variantName + "=" + variant.getByOrdinal(stack.getMetadata()));` in your code. This string is what actually maps the metadata to a different model. My variants were all enum specified and hard mapped `metadata <-> enum ordinal`.
2. I don't see a call to `ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation()` which is what tells the game how to go find a resource for that string.

Its possible that your code does contain those things, but you haven't included it in the question, making it very difficult to figure out where things are going wrong.

1. <sub>Note that the class I've linked here is one half of a system that I custom built to handle the RegistryEvent systems in a way that was more friendly to having transitioned from 1.7.10's `GameRegistry` system. There's some odd redirections involved shoving data into arrays only to [read them back out again later](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1.12.1/src/main/java/com/draco18s/hardlib/client/ClientEasyRegistry.java#L180-L200) that's not actually necessary if you just construct items *in* the relevant event (which is [the more widely accepted standard](https://github.com/Cadiboo/Example-Mod/blob/1.12.2/src/main/java/io/github/cadiboo/examplemod/EventSubscriber.java#L38-L52)). I do all the same things, just at a different point.</sub>

Comment: ive figured out the solution, i haven't added a hasSubTypes(true) to item's class xD

Comment: @Mccoring Ah yes, that too. Because I've moved on to 1.14 (with The Flattening in full effect) I'd forgotten about that functionality.